# overlayfs mounted - but writing fails as "read-only file system"

Tags: filesystem, overlayfs

I try a simple overlay example by mounting:
        sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/tmp/lower,upperdir=/tmp/upper/upper, workdir=/tmp/upper/workdir none /tmp/overlay

(I run the full script from example in  : https://blog.programster.org/overlayfs)

The mount is successful:

```
/tmp/lower-fs.img on /tmp/lower type ext4 (ro)
/tmp/upper-fs.img on /tmp/upper type ext4 (rw)
none on /tmp/overlay type overlay 
(rw,lowerdir=/tmp/lower,upperdir=/tmp/upper/upper,workdir=/tmp/upper/workdir)
```

Yet, I get error on trying to write into the readonly and overlayed area:

```
 echo "hello world" >> /tmp/lower/lower-file.txt
 bash: /tmp/lower/lower-file.txt: Read-only file system
```

I use the following kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux user-VirtualBox 4.4.50-040450-generic #201702181144 SMP Sat Feb 18 
 16:45:38 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks for any idea

Answer (score 3):

You need to write to the *overlay* mount. The command you pasted is trying to write directly to the lower layer, which is indeed mounted read-only...

Use this instead, it should work:

```
$ echo "hello world" >> /tmp/overlay/lower-file.txt
```

Note that you'll see the contents of the lower layer in your `/tmp/overlay` mount, but any modifications you make will go to the upper layer (under the hood), while you'll get a merged view of the layers under your overlay mount point, which is the one you're supposed to access.

Comment: thanks very much, but I thought the idea of overlay is that if we try to write to the readonly area, it will still succeed. and if it fails , it won't help.

Comment: @ransh Not quite... The idea of overlayfs is that you get a new mount that is a *merge* of your readonly area (lower layer) with a readwrite/scratch area on top (upper layer), so that you can get a new mount (the overlay one) where you can find all the files in your readonly area, but that you can still modify. Does that clear it up?

Comment: @ransh From the blog post you mentioned: "Now you can still write to lower-file.txt **in the overlay filesystem** even though it only appears because it is in the lower filesystem. This is because *any changes you make* are actually made *in the upper filesystem*." In other words, `/tmp/overlay` is merging the two of them, shows you the contents of the readonly lower layer, but if you modify anything, that goes into the writable upper layer.